# jQuery with ajax:true parameter

Tags: jquery, json

```
$.getJSON('${userDetailsURL}', {
    Id :  "${user.id}",
    ajax : 'true'
},..... etc...
```

What is ajax:'true' for? I couldn't figure it out.

Thanks a lot

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: I have the same question. I was watching the Spring MVC on Pluralsight.com and the getJSON call is made with the data object {ajax: 'true'}. On the server side the controller is returning a List<Activity>.  The controller method does not do anything with the data object directly. I imagine that it's being used by the Spring framework but the question is what?  The lesson does not explain what the ajax: 'true' is used for.  My guess is that it's used as a way to tell the browser to use a callback handler instead of rendering the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter containing the `ajax:true` part is the data being sent to the server.

My guess would be that the user is checking for the existence of ajax: true when the call is made so they can do something differently (or to verify) when the url is hit by an ajax call rather than directly (or through some other means).

Answer (score 0):

It's a parameter that gets sent to the remote server in the query string.